# how to set range for textfield in swift

Tags: swift2

I have 2 textfield which accepts month in MM formate, year in YYYY formate.I want to set range to textfield so that month textfield should accept only the value form 01-12 and year should accept valid four digit year.

i have used the following code but it is not enough  it is not setting a range to month

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
    let maxLength = 4
    let currentString: NSString = textField.text
    let newString: NSString =
             currentString.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
    return newString.length <= maxLength
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set month text field tag 2(required max length) and year text field tag 4(required max length) and add below code in shouldChangeCharactersInRange method

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
    {
        let maxLength = textField.tag // dynamic tag form IB
        var isAllow:Bool = true
        isAllow = NSCharacterSet.alphanumericCharacterSet().isSupersetOfSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: string))
        if (isAllow && ((range.location < maxLength && (range.length == 0) && (((textField.text?.characters.count)! + string.characters.count) <= maxLength)) || ((range.length > 0) && (((string.characters.count + (textField.text?.characters.count)!) - range.length) <= maxLength)))) {
            if  textField.tag == 2 && string.characters.count > 0 && textField.text?.characters.count > 0 { //condition for month text field
                let newString: NSString = (textField.text! as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
                return newString.integerValue >= 1 && newString.integerValue <= 12
            }
            //you can any custom conditions for year text field also
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```